# Why Oracle cannot resolve Service Name?

Tags: c++, database, oracle, oracle12c

I want to use OCILIB

https://vrogier.github.io/ocilib/doc/html/group___ocilib_cpp_api_demo_list_application.html

using this first example code, running on `Visual Studio 2019`

```
// dbconnect.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ocilib.hpp"

using namespace ocilib;


//Declaration:
int test_odbc()
{
    try
    {
        Environment::Initialize();

        Connection con("ORCL", "test", "test");

        Statement st(con);
        st.Execute("select intcol, strcol from table");

        Resultset rs = st.GetResultset();
        while (rs.Next())
        {
            std::cout << rs.Get<int>(1) << " - " << rs.Get<ostring>(2) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    Environment::Cleanup();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;


}

int main()
{
    test_odbc();
}
```

for connection to a locally installed Oracle 12 database.

At Connection con... I get:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Same when I use `orcl.ad001.siemens.net` instead of `ORCL`.

I can connect via SQLDeveloper as follows:

[image]

The tns.ora is as follows:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\atw11a92\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.ad001.siemens.net)
    )
  )
```

I can tnsping ORCL:

```
C:\Users\atw11a92>tnsping ORCL

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-DEC-2019 11:12:09

Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\atw11a92\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.ad001.siemens.net)))
OK (0 msec)

C:\Users\atw11a92>
```

Any Idea? I'm completely discouraged...

Comment: The error seems to say that you execution env does not have a pointer to where your tnsnames.ora is stored. Try setting TNS_ADMIN to where this file is stored. Another thing, did you try in sqldev to use a TNS alias, and not jdbc connection spec?

Comment: C:\Users\atw11a92>echo %TNS_ADMIN%
C:\app\atw11a92\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin - the same...

Comment: I've got n experience nor access to Visual Studio, but from the internet, I gather that you can set env variable to some values when starting an app, try doing that to fix TNS_ADMIN, just in case it is taking some other value than you command line session.